# How to filter data from struct array when certain fields are empty

Tags: matlab

I have a struct array with certain fields. Now I want to filter all the rows in which certain fields are empty.

Basically what I have now is:

```
data(1).elem1 = 1;
data(1).elem2 = 2;
data(1).elem3 = 3;
data(2).elem1 = 4;
data(2).elem3 = 6;
data(3).elem1 = 7;
data(3).elem2 = 8;
data(4).elem1 = 9;
data(4).elem2 = 10;
data(4).elem3 = 11;
data(5).elem1 = 9;
data(5).elem3 = 11;

data

fields = {'elem2,elem3'};

data(any(~cellfun(@(x) any(~isempty(x)), {data.('elem2'); data.('elem3')}))) = [];
```

This works okay. However, I do not want to express `{data.('elem2'); data.('elem3')}` specifically. I want to simply use the variable `fields`.

I can loop around fields and create a temporary variable which contains `{data.('elem2'); data.('elem3')}`. However I prefer not to do this. Because I think there is a more clever way and I am wondering if it not can be done more efficient as I am doing currently.

Comment: You have a mistake in defining `fields`. It should be `fields = {'elem2', 'elem3'};`. Then you can write `data(any(cellfun(@(x) isempty(x), {data.(fields{1});data.(fields{2})}))) = [];` (you have one extra `any` and 2 extra negation!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the struct to a cell and use `cellfun` to check for empty values for *any* field. Then use `ismember` to find the index of the fields to check.

```
fields = {'elem2','elem3'};
emptyIdx = squeeze(cellfun('isempty', struct2cell(data)));
idxToRemove = any(emptyIdx(ismember(fieldnames(data), fields),:), 1);
```

Example:

```
data(1).elem1 = 1;
data(1).elem2 = 2;
data(1).elem3 = 3;
data(2).elem1 = 4;
data(2).elem3 = 6;
data(3).elem1 = 7;
data(3).elem2 = 8;
data(4).elem1 = 2;
data(4).elem3 = 5;
data(4).elem2 = 4;
```

Gives data struct with only index 1 and 4

```
data = 
1x2 struct array with fields:
    elem1
    elem2
    elem3
```

Comment: While I think I can use parts of the code, the code does not function as I want, try to test it with the example data set. It does not remove any elements.

Comment: The code actually filters on fields not on elements of `data`. Try your code with my added dataset. The reason it worked because the number of elements were equal to the number of fields.

Comment: @WG- True, mixed row and column. Updated my solution using `squeeze`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it

```
I=ismember(fieldnames(data), {'elem2', 'elem3'});
data(~arrayfun(@(x) any(I & structfun(@isempty, x)), data))=[];
```

Find the indices of fields of interest. Iterate over all elements of `data` using `arrayfun`, and then iterate over all fields using `structfun` and ignore the fields that we are not interested in by `I & ...`.